# A object attribute is showing as undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const markMiller = {
  firstname: 'Mark',
  secondName: 'Miller',
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,
  calcbmi: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  },
};
const johnSmith = {
  firstname: 'john',
  secondName: 'Smith',
  mass: 92,
  height: 1.95,
  calcbmi: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  },
};
console.log(typeof (johnSmith.bmi))
console.log(markMiller);
```

Why `bmi` is added as attribute and show as `undefined` ?
I also tried to add the attribute with '[]' notation but the result was same.

Comment: You code does not call the `calcbmi()` function.

Comment: Because you are not calling the function that calculates the bmi ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 1):

You don't define a attribute called bmi in this code snippet. You'll have to add it while creating like this:

```
const johnSmith = {
  firstname: 'john',
  secondName: 'Smith',
  mass: 92,
  height: 1.95,
  bmi: 12345 // HERE
  calcbmi: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  },
};
```

or if you want to calculate it using your function you'll have to call

```
johnSmith.calcbmi()
```

Now you can access johnSmith.bmi